# how can i catch deleted and inserted rows in mysql while using "replace into .." statement

Tags: mysql

i have large table in mysql which contains around 10lakhs records. every day i am uploading around 3000 records which may contains duplicates. to avoid duplicate insertion i used "replace into..." statement while inserting into table. but its not giving deleted and inserted records information while uploading table. i need to show duplicate records as well as replaced records.
  i tried using "innerjoin" and "groupby" on same table to do above work its working but taking toooo much time to upload.
 can anyone tell me how can i catch inserted and replace records while using "Replace into.." statement in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

i would recomment using INSERT IGNORE, It will generate an warning on duplicated row and you can check warnings info:

> If you use INSERT IGNORE, then the row won't actually be inserted if
>   it results in a duplicate key. But the statement won't generate an
>   error. It generates a warning instead. These cases include:
>
> 1. Inserting a duplicate key in columns with PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints.
> 2. Inserting a NULL into a column with a NOT NULL constraint.
> 3. Inserting a row to a partitioned table, but the values you insert don't map to a partition

also you can use **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL
>   performs an UPDATE of the old row. REPLACE INTO will delete old row
>   and insert new one.

and there is no way to find which is new and which is updates, you can add a new field named Updated and set its value to 1, then count them:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (Col1, Col2, Updated)
VALUES ("value1", "value2", 0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    Col1 = values(Col1),
    Col2 = values(Col2),
    Updated = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when we use INSERT IGNORE it will ignore all duplicate records. we get first inserted record only. but i need to store last duplicated record in database. this will done using REPLACE. so your answer will not useful at this location... please tell me another...

Comment: what about INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, MySQL performs an UPDATE of the old row. REPLACE INTO will delete old row and insert new one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when we use INSERT IGNORE it will ignore all duplicate records. we get first inserted record only. but i need to store last duplicated(updated) record in database. this will done using REPLACE. so your answer will not useful at this location... please tell me another logic to above query...

Comment: your code will work but as i told in question i need to show duplicate records in GRID to client in a webpage so that i need to get duplicate records which replacing/updating in table.....

Comment: and the is no way to find which is new and which is updated, you can add a new field named Updated and set its value to 1, then count them. answer updated

Comment: to check part of your code i crated two tables "table-a","table-b" with "id,name,course,fee" as columns in both table. now i tried to use   INSERT INTO--ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as follows "insert into `table-b` (`NAME`,`COURSE`,`FEE`) select `NAME`,`COURSE`,`FEE` from `table-a`
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NAME=NAME, COURSE=COURSE, FEE=FEE ;" but i am getting error like--Error Code:1052.Column 'NAME' in field list is ambiguous--i taken two duplicate records and 3 non duplicate records in table-a and tested but its giving error... can you tell me reason..("id"--primary key, "course,fee"-unique key

Comment: name is ambiguous means MySQL don't know witch field you mean, change your query to: "insert into table-b (NAME,COURSE,FEE) select NAME,COURSE,FEE from table-a ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table-b.NAME=table-a.NAME, table-b.COURSE=table-a.COURSE, table-b.FEE=table-a.FEE"

Answer (score 0):

**REPLACE INTO** calls both Delete and Insert trigger so you can add trigger to your table that will be keeping record of deleted and inserted rows in some other temp tables and then every time trigger is called you can clear previous data in temp tables just in case if you only need recent inserted/deleted records.